# Raspberry pi raspbmc display turns off after being inactive for a while

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian-based

Hope somebody can help me.

I have a raspberry pi with the raspbmc distro loaded, connected to a tv via hdmi. There's no mouse or keyboard attached as all control is done by iPad apps.

After being inactive for a while (such as overnight) the display turns off, audio still works but there is no display. If i connect via ssh the display reactivates.

Is there any way to stop the display turning off?

Thanks for you help.
Rob

Comment: Update - connecting by ssh only reactivates the display if the tv is not on that hdmi channel. If i;m watching normal tv, ssh to the pi and then switch channels to the hdmi it works. If i switch to the hdmi and then ssh in it doesn't display anything..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the forum's suggestion to use custom timer from XBMC or TV settings

http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=2953